# Returning News Articles on the News Feature of Google Between Specific Dates in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, google-news

I am currently building a simple media tracker (tried in a previous question but restarted from scratch) in python for a small organization that I work for. It works by searching key words on the news feature of google and returning all of the links that appear on the google search page. Where I am running into a problem is that I am trying to narrow my search to articles between specific dates by changing the original URL searched. While my code creates a link that yields articles based on my key words in the specific date requested, when I attempt to make a list of these links, for some reason, they are not within my requested date. Why may this be happening and how can I fix the problem?

Below is a sample code. When I click on the link: "https://www.google.com/search?q=Center+for+Community+Alternatives&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:5/2/2019,cd_max:5/10/2019&tbm=nws" it gives me articles for search result between my dates, however, the list generated does not reflect the articles that appear.

```
import requests
import re
import bs4
import urllib
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from urllib.request import urlopen

search = 'Center+for+Community+Alternatives'
start_date = '5/2/2019'
end_date = '5/10/2019'

# The link to be searched initially 
link4 = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=' + search + '&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:' + start_date + ',cd_max:' + end_date + '&tbm=nws'

# Searching the link
page = requests.get(link4)

# Gathering the page content from the link
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content)

# Finding all links
links = soup.findAll("a")

# Fixing up the links and putting them into a list
empty = []
fixed_list = []
finished_list = []
for link in  soup.find_all("a",href=re.compile("(?<=/url\?q=)(htt.*://.*)")):
    the = (re.split(":(?=http)",link["href"].replace("/url?q=","")))
    empty.append(the)
for link in empty:
    fixed_list.append(link[0])
for link in fixed_list:
    finished_list.append(link.split('&sa',1)[0])


# The list of links
finished_list

# The original link searched
print(link4)
```

Note: I have tried using the googlenews module, however this does NOT give me the search results that I am looking for - the news feature on google is different than google news.